# Wrapper properties fail to load while building android apk, ionic 2 project

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to build an apk for my Ionic 2 project and when I run Ionic build android i get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main"  java.lang.runtime exception could not load wrapper properties from "C:\Users\Naomi Gloria\CampoApp\platforms\android\gradle\wrapper"
```

I have set the environment for `JAVA_HOME` and `ANDROID_HOME`
 and followed all other requirements but i still get the error.

I am not using a network with proxy so I do not think that could be the problem.

I am using the following versions:

**Cordova 6.5.0** -- **npm 3.10.0** -- **ionic 2.2.1** -- **node 6.10.0** -- **android 6.1.0**

on Windows 7 professional

[image: Screenshot]

Can someone please help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328422/getting-a-loading-wrapper-properties-error-in-android

Comment: @CaptainHere I already downloaded gradle 2.2.1.zip, put it in local folder and edited the directory in gradlebuilder file.

Comment: I have managed to remove the above but still when i run **ionic build android** i get the following error
>ERROR: failed to instantiate GradleBuilder builder: syntaxerror: unexpected token :
I have downloaded gradle.zip file and edited the path in gradlebuilder file but i still get the same error.
1. What might be the problem?
2. Or do i need to edit gradle.builder?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43677221/4826457

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, what I did was to delete the android folder in the platform folder and I ran ionic cordova build android.
Hope this help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this issue is due to java doesn't have enough  run time memory to compile actually i have face the same issue on Windows 7 so after searching a lot i found solution. and it just to increase Run time memory of JAVA.

Hope you know the process of increasing java run time memory. If not please let me know.