# i am working with android studio 4.0 and facing the error message could not load wraper properties

Tags: android, gradle

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9r6Q.jpg)

I am working on a project with android studio 4.0 and stuck here. I am getting an error that says

```
Could not load wrapper properties from c:\users\rishabh\androidstudioprojects\animations\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties.
```

Comment: Hey @rishabh, welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be great if instead of adding images, you add the error directly here. Please check this [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: yaa sure from next time I will remember. @SONUSOURAV I urgently need the solution can u please help me out.

Comment: does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36328422/8192914) solve your issue?

Comment: no, @ganjaam actually I am using the latest android version  and that solution is too old and not working on this

Answer (score 0):

Update the gradle distribution to latest version. Replace you distribution URL to below:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip`

Also, make sure `Toggle Offline Mode` is off. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57797772/cannot-enable-gradles-offline-mode-on-android-studio-3-6) how to do that. It should look like the below image

[image: this]

Comment: I am yet getting the same issue

Comment: Just to confirm, make sure the button looks like in the picture. Don't do opposite i.e. toggle it on ( which will enable offline build)

Comment: any other solution to this problem?